# Apache server A attempts conn to mysql server B. times out

Tags: networking, apache2, mysql

I have an apache web server running PHP. I am trying to make a connection from apache server to a database server running mysql server. Heres a run down of the settings in place.

- apache server: RHEL 5.5; PHP 5.3.2
- database server: Ubuntu 10.04 64bit; mysql server version 5.1
- There are no firewall rules restricting connections between these two machines. neither in our hardware firewall or in iptables.
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf has the bind-address set to the machine's ip.
- skip-networking is commented out, ie disabled.
- mysql is running and on the standard port 3306
- /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock is owned by mysql
- i can connect to mysql locally

the following is my php connection script:

```
<?php

$host="555.555.55.55";
$user="some_user"; 
$pass="some_pass";   

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if ($conn === FALSE) { echo mysql_error(); } 
else { echo 'Connected'; mysql_close($conn); }

?>
```

attempting to execute the php script in a browser hosted on the apache server only yields: "Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '555.555.55.55' (4)"

any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried connecting to the remote mysql server with command-line tools yet?  I would do that first to isolate it to msql problems or php implementation problem....on the RHEL box use mysql -u--------whatever command to connect directly to the remote database to isolate the problem

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Comment: This appears to be abandoned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed the ip of the machine to a different ip range within our institution. from a private range to a public ip. it now connects. We're now investigating this private range. Thanks for everyones help!

https://serverfault.com/questions/200774/apache-server-a-attempts-conn-to-mysql-server-b-times-out-what-am-i-missing/201308#201308

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule simple things out, have you tried running `ps -A | grep mysqld` on the Ubuntu server? If there is no text output here, the server is not actually running.

Can you connect to the MySQL server by running `mysql -u root -p` from a terminal on the Ubuntu machine? If so, can you also connect using `mysql -u root -p -h <ubuntu-server-ip>` from your Red Hat server?

Your PHP script seems fine, though for what it's worth you will typically want to make a more explicit comparison when checking your $conn variable, like:

`if ($conn === FALSE) { echo mysql_error(); } else { echo 'Connected'; }`

Also, if `$conn` is set to `FALSE`, calling `mysql_close($conn)` at the bottom is a waste of server time (`mysql_close(FALSE)` will take up time to return FALSE silently); you only need to free a valid resource identifier, and in this case (a non-persistent connection) you don't need to explicitly free the resource anyway.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I can connect to mysql locally with "mysql -u root -p". Also "ps -A | grep mysqld" does list a process for the server.

Comment: Thanks for the PHP tips! mysql -u root -p -h <ubuntu-server-ip> from redhat yields: "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<ubuntu-server-ip>' (110)"

Comment: MySQL server on '<ubuntu-server-ip>' (110) makes it look like it is trying to connect on the wrong port...not a php guy though so I really can't say 100%

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I didn't mention, you need to replace <ubuntu-server-ip> with the IP of your Ubuntu server. And happy to help regarding the PHP.

Comment: heh, thanks, i knew what you meant, ie the ip was changed.

Comment: @ifeltalive: 110 is not the port it is trying to connect and is not related to mysql. It is the error number. it means that 'Connection timed out'. just try this command telnet <ipaddress of ubuntu server> 3306. and check the output.